# TinyMCE insert responsive video

Tags: video, youtube, tinymce, embed, responsive

Anyone aware of a plug-in or way for non coders to insert video/embed YouTube videos responsively in the TinyMCE editor? Fine for coders to create a wrapper and use the padding trick for 16:9, 4.3 or use pre-written classes etc... but for non coders a drop in solution is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a (premium) plugin for TinyMCE called [Enhanced Media Embed](https://apps.tiny.cloud/products/enhanced-media-embed/) that inserts responsive youtube videos.